# TIFF file and image converting (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I don't know much about image types, especially when it comes to an extension called .tif.

My current customer obtains the case results from the court as a .tif file by connecting to Court database via SOAP/CURL. Right now, he is manually converting every .tif file to .jpeg with a third party application and uploading them to his server. However, he is having storage issues because the documents sometimes may be bigger than 100 pages, hence 100 different .tif files.

He also told me that the .tif files the database sends is pretty small comparing to his JPEG types so he's willing to upload them directly if he can find a way to show .tif files in the website.

Basically, we have two task:

1. Find a way to show .tif image files in website and avoid .jpeg conversions, or;
2. Find a way to covert .tif files into popular image types (like gif, png, jpg) with smallest size as possible (User still should be able to read the text written.) so we can show them with html img tag.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for long term solutions instead of saving the day.

Ps. the Court db doesn't send anything else except .tif files.

Comment: Sounds like you could automate the conversion of TIFF to JPEG files, perhaps using a PHP script on a cronjob? The website could just then read from the JPEG folder, rather than the TIFF folder at present.

Comment: Does JPEG has the minimum size? It's already automated. This is one example of an output by .tif to .jped convert. (http://i.imgur.com/XkxsT.jpg) The file size is 280kb. I want to lower it as much as I can without making the text unreadable.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that bit. What is the third party application that does this? Perhaps you can reduce the "quality setting" - maybe down to about 60/100; it may presently be too high.

Comment: I don't know anything about what software/script they're using right now. I can write one myself using PHP (or C++) as soon as I learn what imagetype should I convert/what quality settings should I apply. I'm pretty sure they're using a lackily coded script just to convert .tif to .jpeg.

Comment: I'd use ImageMagick, it's easy. Something like `convert -quality 65 in.tif out.jpg`. That can be called from a shell script directly, or one of PHP's system calls if you're more comfortable with that. (Also, see @user1654209's similar approach for GIF output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you end up with bigger jpeg files than the TIFF file this maybe means that the TIFF files are CCIT Fax4 images (bilevel images often generated by scanner software) and that your JPEG files end up as RGB (24bit) images. The best you can do while targeting the web is to convert them as either GIF or paletized PNG files. I would'nt go with JPEG compression as it will generate too much artefacts on black and white text images.

Comment: Yes, good point about the unsuitability of JPEG. It won't be terrible, but GIF is probably better.

Comment: Okay, I can covert it to GIF but what other settings I can change inside the .GIF file?

Comment: If you're using imagemagick you can force the image to bilevel using a command like this : convert XkxsT.jpg -type Bilevel out.gif